# Ignore all files with the same base name in git

Tags: git, gitignore

I have some auto generated files that I need to ignore, they all have different names but everyone of them start with: "._ " for example:

```
/classes/Admin/._Subscribers.php
/classes/Admin/._Support.php
/admin/._about.php
```

I have about 1k of those files that I need to ignore, so if you help me fount a way to ignore them all at once that will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a trivial glob pattern problem. `._*` matches the names. (Note: that's a *glob pattern*, which is what .gitignore implements. It is not a regular expression, which is what grep uses.)

Comment: Thank you, this worked

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
._*
```

to your gitignore file and all those files will be ignored. You can use wildcards patterns in `gitignore` file.